# Mac OS X Javascript for Automation displayDialog

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, javascript-automation

I'm trying to get a simple dialog to show for a workflow I'm working on, but using JXA I keep getting the error: Expecting object specifier, argument has no object specifier. I don't know what to pass in for the object Specifier. My code is below, it takes issue at line 11 where I call the dialog

```
function run() {

    app = Application.currentApplication();
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    //Error Here
    var who = app.displayDialog('Whose server is this?', {
        withTitle: 'Whose Server...'
    })

    return who
}
```

Comment: I copied your code 1:1 into Script Editor and switched to JavaScript. Everything works as expected on 10.10.3! *just my 2 cents*

Comment: Did you click the cancel button? which may produce an error 128

Comment: As @ShooTerKo has stated: this code looks perfectly fine. Was your problem due to using a prerelease version? Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: No. I switched to traditional apple script

Answer (score 1):

Read this unofficial [cookbook about User-Interactions](https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/User-Interactions), it helps me about these alert things.

In details:

```
function prompt(text, defaultAnswer) {
  var options = { defaultAnswer: defaultAnswer || '' }
  try {
    return app.displayDialog(text, options).textReturned
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: ++ for the link and the handy function, but your answer doesn't explain the OP's problem (which is mysterious, given that his code looks perfectly fine).

Answer (score -2):

From Gary @ macmost.com https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcPUJzmEuKE @ 8:47

```
app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

color = app.displayDialog("What is your favorite color?", { defaultAnswer: "" }).textReturned;

if (color == "red") {
    app.displayDialog("I like red too!");
} else {
    app.displayDialog("Interesting, I like red myself.");
}
```